# Como instalar git repository urbanaccess utilizando anaconda prompt?

Tags: git, github, conda

estoy utilizando anaconda prompt para descargar datos de osm y gtfs para crear graficos y, para poder instalar urbanaccess, tengo que clonar el git repository, sin embargo, no se como puedo hacerlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionada en StackOverflow en ingles:

Primero instalar git:

conda install git

Luego:

git clone https://github.com/UDST/urbanaccess.git

Ubicarse en el directorio e instalar:

cd urbanaccess

python setup.py develop

Gracias a John Morrison.